# split a multi-lingual string (French-Arabic)

Tags: c#, .net, split

I want to split a multi-lingual string .

for example for this French-Arabic string :

```
String texte="aaaa bbbb عععع تتت ccc";
String[] spl=texte.split(' ');
```

The result must be as below:

```
aaaa
bbbb 
تتت
عععع  
ccc
```

But I have this result:

```
aaaa
bbbb
عععع
تتت
ccc
```

PLZ Help me ! thank you

Comment: If you think your question is different - please make sure to explain in what way the linked question does not explain behavior you see. And explain what additional information you need to solve your problem.